# Tool for auto generating return code checker

Tags: c, code-generation, static-analysis

I'm looking for a tool which generates subroutine for checking a return code of some other subroutine.

For example, `pthread_create` can returns `0`, `EAGAIN`, `EINVAL` and `EPERM` codes.  It would be nice to have such checker:

```
void pthread_create_check(int retcode) {
    switch (retcode) {
    case 0:
        printf("pthread_create success.\n");
        break;
    case EAGAIN:
        printf("pthread_create EAGAIN error: insufficient resources"
               " to create another thread, or a system-imposed"
               " limit on the number of threads was encountered.\n");
        break;
    case EINVAL:
        printf("pthread_create EINVAL error: invalid settings in"
               " attr.\n");
        break;
    case EPERM:
        printf("pthread_create EPERM error: no permission to set the"
               " scheduling policy and parameters specified in"
               " attr.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

And use it in such manner:

```
iret = pthread_create(&thread_desc, 
                      NULL, 
                      thread_function, 
                      (void *) thread_param);
pthread_create_check(iret);
```

There are explanation of each error code in man page.  Creating such checker is nothing but copy-paste error codes and explanation from man page.  I think that computer can done this job much better than human since computer never get tire.  Also, I'm too lazy to do it for every subroutine call.  Is there any automation tool?

Comment: please clarify: do you mean you want a _generic_ code generator that generates a return code checker for _any_ library call from the man page? (_In that case (a) good luck (b) my best recommendation would be the awesome `ptrace` syscall interface to intercept calls at runtime)

Comment: Yep, I want a code generator.  I'll happy even with non-generic generator which understands common subroutines, e.g. `fopen`, `mq_send`.  Why do you think it is impossible?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it is far beyond practical. The reason is that there is no standard formatting for error codes in `man` pages. Those pages are intended to be read by humans, not machines, so they are not strictly checked. Also, the phrasing is not the same as what you want to see in an error message. Of course, if you have access to something like IBM's Watson you might have a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make message tables. It will save coding time and space.

```
typedef struct pthread_message {
    int code;
    const char* text;
} pthread_message;

int pthread_check(int retcode, const char* fname, 
    pthread_message* messages)
{
    if(!retcode) /* Makes the common case fast. */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s success.\n", fname);
        return retcode;
    }

    /* Look for a message. */
    for(; messages->code; ++messages)
        if(messages->code == retcode)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", fname, message->text);
            return retcode;
        }

    /* Fall back on standard library. If you lack strerror_r, 
       then put a generic message here.
    */
    char buf[256];
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", fname, strerror_r(retcode, buf, 256));
    return retcode;
);

pthread_message pthread_create_messages[] = {
    { EAGAIN, "EAGAIN error: insufficient resources to create another thread,"
      " or a system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered." },
    { EINVAL, "EINVAL error: invalid settings in attr." },
    { EPERM, "EPERM error: no permission to set the scheduling policy and"
      " parameters specified in attr." },
    { 0, 0 } /* End of list. */
};

iret = pthread_check(pthread_create(arg1, arg2, ...), "pthread_create", 
    pthread_create_messages);
```

There's nothing stopping you from sharing message lists between functions, so you can write as little or as much as you want.

If you're insane, you can make a macro out of the call:

```
#define PTHREAD_CHECK(fname, arglist) \
    (pthread_check(fname arglist, #fname, fname##_messages))

iret = PTHREAD_CHECK(pthread_create, (arg1, arg2, ...));
```

In this case, to share a message list means you need to create a pointer with the proper name for each additional function pointing to the list of the first function. Still a lot less work.

For the record, I just wrote one check function with generic messages (except for the success messages, they're spammy) and used it everywhere in my C++ wrapper around pthread. (Don't carp at me about Boost, this was ten years ago.)

Comment: Very interesting approach!  This decreases amount of work but there is still a lot of routine.  Your profile says that you are very experienced C++ developer.  What do you think about tool that generates checkers from man pages?  Does it helpful?  Which approach is used in real-life coding?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough consistency in man page formatting to make such a tool feasible. Parsing of well-formed input is a lot of work by itself; adding all the code to handle oddball things will result in you putting far more effort into the project than simply copying and pasting the messages and making tables as above. In real-life, the usual case is people ignore error codes and hope for the best (BAD!), followed by checking for nonzero and optionally calling `strerror`. Sometimes they'll make a macro which uses `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to report where the failed call was in the code.

Comment: TL;DR: You're putting far more effort into this already than most programmers bother with in real life, so I'd be worried about going overboard, spending all your time on error handling and not on coding the actual application. Seek balance.

Comment: Thank you for answer and comments!  The opinion of an experienced person is indispensable.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind's Helgrind can detect misuses of the POSIX pthreads API.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.api-checks

Comment: Hm, Valgrind is a powerful tool.  Does it have similar functionality for other common subroutines, e.g. `fopen`?